# scroll fixed navigation height percent

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to fix my vertical navigation on the left side of my site.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var border = 150;
        if($(window).scrollTop() >= border){
            $("#box_CATEGORIES").css({
                    'position' : 'fixed',
                    'top' : '0'

            });
        }
        if($(window).scrollTop() < border){
            $('#box_CATEGORIES').removeAttr('style');
        }
    })

});
```

This worked first fine but now I changed the height of my site in `100%` because i want the footer always on bottom of the site.

And because of that ( I think ) the code doesnt work anymore.. :(
any help?

Comment: can we see sample code, or a link to the site?!

Comment: http://www.holzverpackung.ch/webshop/

Comment: category "Paletten" then scroll down menu should fix after the header is away

Comment: if you remove overflow-x:hidden from the body it will work fine

Comment: great! thank you! but why overflow-x ? isnt that horizontal?

Comment: please find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to remove the overflow-x:hidden from the body element.

@James Khoury answered on similar
[Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421966/css-overflow-x-visible-and-overflow-y-hidden-causing-scrollbar-issue) by:

> If you are using visible for either overflow-x or overflow-y and
>   something other than visible for the other. The visible value is
>   interpreted as auto.

Also you can find this jQuery open issue on
   [github](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/2215)